# XJC: Create classes with public fields

Tags: jaxb, field, xjc

I'm using XJC to create Java classes from an XML schema file.

The fields in the created classes are *protected*, which  used to be ok for me.
But now I'm doing some Tomcat-BlazeDS-Flash-Java-Serializing stuff where I need the fields of the generated classes to be *public*.

Can XJC be configured to do exactly that?

Comment: Are you sure they need to be public?  It's a rare framework that demands something so boneheaded.

Comment: Well, I tried to get it done with "implicit" converting, which only converts public fields, as you can read here. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an XJC plugin to get this behaviour.  The link below has some pointers for creating a plugin:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html

Comment: +1: A plugin which creates and configures a field renderer factory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it seemes to be the right one. I gave it a try and came to know that I only needed to extend the com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.SingleField class. Its parent class AbstractFieldWithVar has a method where the field is created and set to protected. So I just need to override this method. Unfortunately it's a final method. :-(

Comment: @Morrandir - Glad I could help, if it answers your question I ask that you consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: You were too fast... or I was too slow. :-)